# How to create or retrieve custom history object data in test class

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have custom object as maze and its history object as maze_history
I am able to create a data for maze object but i am failing to create a test data for custom history object.

here is mu test class sample code

```
maze__c m = new maze__c(Enrollee__c = contactId,Carrier_Name__c='CARO');

Insert m;

m.EDI_mazeStartDate__c=date.newInstance(Date.today().year(), 3, Date.today().day());

Update m;

maze__History eh=  [Select ParentId, Field, OldValue, NewValue 
                      from Enrollment__History  where ParentId = :m.Id];
```

where `parentID` is a Parent `object(maze) id`.

I am not getting any query result for above query

Comment: History records are not created when you create the records in test classes. You will have to use the data from the org to cover these lines

Comment: and how could i use org data?what should be my approach?

Comment: You will have to make sure the record which satisfies the condition are already present in the org and then you will have to use the `(seeAlldata=true)` flag with the `@isTest` annotation to fetch the records from the db in test classes

Comment: Can u please share an example to demonstrate use of (seeAlldata=true) in test class. A link would help.

Comment: Check my answer here. You can do the same thing for case history during tests. I did exactly this for case history http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/test-class-error-compile-error-field-is-not-writeable-opportunity-connectio/115666#115666